# Jquery JSON - Detect if a certain key exists

Tags: jquery, json, google-api

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty('date'){
     var start = data.date
}else{
    var start = data.datetime
}
```

This is an example of the code I'm trying to use - Though it fails to work, always returning only of the two options. Other things I have tried is using if(data.key), typeof...

So to provide more information about the issue - I'm trying to fetch data from a google api server. The data fetches correctly in the fact that I can display data fetched from the server clearly. The issue lies in the fact that my client uses two different formats for receiving start and end date. Date which is a YYYY-MM-DD format, and DateTime which also provides a hour. The api deals with showing the correct one by only showing that key. Meaning it either shows a date or a datetime key, never both. Hence I'm trying to detect if one of the keys exists, but calling upon them seems to return "undefined" and I'm drawing a blank on how to make it work.

An example of the JSON returned by the api:

```
"start": {"date": "2015-03-20"}
```

In some cases the date key will instead be datetime, and provide the other format.

Hence my question is, how does one make sure that only the correct key is called upon, if the other key returns undefined?

I'm using Jquery + Jquery mobile. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you fiddle your code?Also edit your question with complete code

Comment: Edited my code for a bit more clarity, though I can guarantee the code is actually coming through - It's just detecting the proper key.

It's also a bit more difficult than just fiddling I'm afraid - The code is written for a large part in dutch as that's the language we're using, and secondly it's a bit hard to properly show some data where it shows both the date and datetime being used. With that being said I quickly cooked this up - You can view datetime when adjusting the date to 2015-3-19. Sorry if it's a bit messy, css didn't take over completely.

https://jsfiddle.net/pyavrjaj/6/

Comment: To add to it, if you want to view the returned json: These are the two returned json files:

19/3: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/vdckbkdr85fvopf88mi1327o00%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyD3EZ-traQ21fhwZtJJv6zenQi3w9r5AEw&orderby=starttime&singleevents=true&timeMin=2015-03-19T00:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2015-03-20T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: And the second one, since these links are too long to post them in one comment: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/vdckbkdr85fvopf88mi1327o00%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyD3EZ-traQ21fhwZtJJv6zenQi3w9r5AEw&orderby=starttime&singleevents=true&timeMin=2015-03-20T00:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2015-03-21T00:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 0):

And once again, capitalization ends up being the fault. I was searching for the property datetime, while the json returned dateTime with a capitalized t.

My apologies for the unnecessary trouble - I think we all know how sometimes your stumped by the easiest of answers. For future reference, it's important to note that json IS case-sensitive.